# Getting form data from html form into google script API

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-api, gmail

I need to get the value for the addr var from an html form into the below google script API, so whenever an user enters an email id in the input field and clicks the submit button ...an email must be sent to that mail id through this API.
I have used static value for the addr var in the below example.Kindly help me with this.

```
function doPost(){
  var addr="example@abc.com";
  MailApp.sendEmail(addr,
                   "Recovery email for TracerSC",
                   "Your one time password ");
 }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46423710/dynamic-mail-id-in-mail-service-app-of-google-apps-script
has the answer